# How to get database retrieved value in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to update a likes on database when a user clicks on "like"(same as facebook like). I will load various posts from database. For each posts there is a unique field on database called mid(message Id) and when user clicks "like" below the post i want to increment likes on database for that specific message(it can be through mid). I want to implement this function using jquery because if i pass mid through url it will navigate to that page and get loaded whole page so i need to done it behind the page through AJAX call. Let me show a model how my database retrieval is

```
$cot = "select * from posts where userid = $usr LIMIT 10";
$ex = mysql_query($cot, $con);
while($cont = mysql_fetch_array($ex))
{
    $date = date_create($cont['date']);
    $mid = $cont['mid'];

    echo "<div id='posts'>";
    echo $cont['message'];
    echo $photo;
    echo "<div class='like'>"; //echo $mid; /* It is to show message id*/ 
    echo "<a href='#'>Like</a></div>";  //When Clicked Like i Want to increment likes on DB
    echo "Likes(" . $cont['Likes'] . ")";
    echo date_format($date, 'd-m-Y H:i:s');
    echo "<hr>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

i want this to be done over jquery and ajax call. I just need jquery code to call php file increment.php and pass mid(message Id) to that page.

Comment: look at the documentation for [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: Thanks. I'm reading its features. My doubt is if server is not updated to php 5 then i have to use mysql_*??

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need something like this:

```
    echo "<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='like' data-mid='".$cont['mid']."'>Like</a></div>";  //When Clicked Like i Want to increment likes on DB
```

Now this is the script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".like").live('click', function(){
           $.ajax({
                url     : 'increment.php',
                data    : {'mid':$(this).data('mid')},
                type    : 'POST',
                success : function(resp){
                    if(resp == '1'){
                        //success message or whatever
                    }
                },
                error   : function(resp){
                    alert("some error occured !");
                }
           }); 
        });
    });
    </script>
```

On your increment.php:

```
    <?php
        $id = $_POST['mid'];
        $sql = "update posts set Likes = Likes+1 where mid = '".$id."'";
        //execute the above and return some thing
        return 1;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('/increment.php', { mid: whatever });
```

With your example click handler, it's simple to add this in....

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
     $("div.pray").click(function() { 
          var mid=$(this).val(); 
          alert(mid);
          $.post('/increment.php', { mid: mid });
     });
 });
```

Comment: I need how to get mid in jquery. $(document).ready(function()
{
$("div.pray").click(function()
{
var  mid=$(this).val();
alert(mid);
});  Like this, corresponding message id.